# Java: Why not declare static intead of passing the reference around?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, static

Let's say we want to make a game where you have to collect gems. So we need a class Gem, a class GemSpawner, and of course the MainActivity-class.

```
public class MainActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Gem> gems = new ArrayList<Gem>();

        GemSpawner gs = new GemSpawner(gems);

        //...
    }
}
```

In this case, we made a List with gems, and passed it to the GemSpawner through it's constructor, so gs can add gems to the list using:

```
gems.add(new Gem(10, 50, "red")); //should represent Xpos, Ypos, and color.
```

But wouldn't this be better:

```
public class MainActivity {

    public static List<Gem> gems = new ArrayList<Gem>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GemSpawner gs = new GemSpawner();

        //...
    }
}
```

now, the GemSpawner (gs) can add gems using:

```
MainActivity.gems.add(new Gem(10, 50, "red"));
```

A friend only showed and explained the above method to me, but isn't the method below much more efficient?

Comment: Your question is a little out of context. Where are these gems in the `gems` array used? You should generally speaking never store stuff that you use regularly in static contexts, even though you can. You could also write all your code inside the `static void main` method, but likewise you would never actually do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a much more complicated question than you may realise.

Many people who begin writing in Java start my making everything `static` exactly because you don't have to pass references around - it makes your code "simpler".

When your code gets more complicated however, you start running into problems. There are 3 main lines along which these problems arise:

1. Encapsulation
2. Abstraction
3. Testing

[**Encapsulation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

This is the idea that an `Object` should not allow access to its members directly, it should be told to "do things" and it does then do that internally without exposing how this is done.

The idea behind this is that you try and avoid too tightly coupling your classes to each other.

This leads us onto the next point

[**Abstraction**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29)

In Java this is represented via `abstract` classes and `interfaces`.

The idea being that your `GemSpawner` is only a definition of something that spawns gems. How it does this internally is really no one's business but its own.

In Java you cannot really reconcile `static` methods with the key OO idea of inheritance.

`static` methods are inherited but they are shadowed rather than overridden so you cannot (easily) modify their behaviour.

And this leads us into

**Testing**

This is a topic that crops up more and more as your program gets more complex.

How do you test a "Hello World" program? Well, you run it and see if it prints "Hello Wrld" - in which case there is a bug.

Once a program gets more complicated you cannot simply do this. You need to break your program apart and test "units". Known as [Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

Here your `static` references really begin to cause issues. You cannot separate your program into discrete units as everything is tied together via direct class references. And you cannot mock the behaviour of the `static` methods because they are not easily overridden.

So, to summarise. Yes; it might well be quicker and easier to put `static` everywhere and not pass around references. **But**, if you are planning on writing something as complicated as a game you should really consider using Java to it's full potential.

Answer (score 7):

The efficiency argument doesn't hold much water. It is a single reference so 32 bits (well 64 bits if you are on a 64bit machine) being parsed once at the start so it isn't having any (measurable) performance effect.

However, the design of your code can become cluttered if you use lots of statics. For example, by making it static, there is no easy way to keep track of what is adding stuff to your list (maybe late one night to test something you randomly add a gem and then forget. Months later, you can't work out why this one gem keeps appearing!)

It seems silly but by restricting access  to things can really help debugging. If you know the only thing that can add a gem is the `GemSpawner`, then you have isolated potential gem based bugs to one class. If it could be coming from anywhere, then debugging can become at lot harder, particularly as your project grows in complexity.

Comment: +1 Also, you cannot have multiple instances of the game running in this way because they'll all be accessing the same gems field, correct me if I'm wrong, but you won't be able to every make your game multiplayer with static fields everwhere.

Answer (score 5):

Static data members introduce what we call a **global state** in your program. Generally, global state is considered bad for a few good reasons:

- It makes the behavior of methods that read the global state **unpredictable**. This has two effects:

  - It's harder to reason about a method whose results depend on more than the object it belongs to and the arguments passed to it.
  - It can make any attempt of formal testing of that method pointless (though there are some exceptions).
- It makes **assumptions** that may hold now but not later on. For example, a procedure that modifies the global state may be fine if it's run strictly once per program run. But later you may have the procedure be run more than once. In that case:

  - In sequence, subsequent iterations will have to be mindful of the "used" state.
  - In parallel, you'll be opening the door to data races and thread unsafety in a way that's hard to create guards against.

On the other hand, if you pass the required state as arguments to each method, you are creating a safety net that automatically makes all the above much less likely to occur and threaten the correctness of your program.

I doubt there's significant performance benefit (or any benefit at all) in choosing a global state over passing the state. And if you do end up in cases of excessive global state validation or, worse, introducing locks and barriers (both scenarios being very costly), you'll have canceled any benefits you would have gained anyway.

Sticking to the good practice of not introducing global state is much more worth it.

Answer (score 4):

A `public static` variable is essentially a global variable.

Global variables are considered very poor programming style among experienced programmers.

[Here is an article which describes some reasons why they are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

An object-oriented solution would be to encapsulate your gems list as a private collection in a GemManager class which exposes any access to the gems through methods. You would then create one instance of the GemManager and pass that instance it to every class or method which needs it.

Answer (score 0):

There is virtually no benefit to using a static variable, but there are downsides:

- You can't create multiple copies of the game either running simultaneously, or even as historical copies - you've locked it at one copy per JVM max
- You have dependencies between classes that needn't exist - See [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29)
- You might want to start the game from another class, but now you can't - you've locked the initiation to your main class
- You have let the implementation "bleed out" into another class - See [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)